# Delete vowels in a list

Tags: prolog

Write a program that deletes vowels (`String`, `NoVowelsString`) that deletes all vowels from a given string.

So far I've got the condition `vowel(X):- member(X,[a,e,i,o,u])`. Then I thought of the one that deletes all the elements from the other list:

```
delete2([],L1,L1).
delete2([H|T],L1,L3) :-
   delete2(H,L1,R2),
   delete2(T,R2,L3).
```

So having these two I thought that I could put a condition to those elements being deleted that they have to be a member of `[a,e,i,o,u]`. Though I still haven't got anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code

```
deleteV([H|T],R):-member(H,[a,e,i,o,u]),deleteV(T,R),!.
deleteV([H|T],[H|R]):-deleteV(T,R),!.
deleteV([],[]).
```

What it does?
First it question itself?It's the head a vowel
Yes->We ignore it.
No->We need it.
If it finds an empty list, it constructs the result list, and when returning from backtracking it appends the consonats in front.
This code was tested in SWIProlog.

Comment: I didn't know about the strings in Prolog.Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The following is based on the [reification of term equality/inequality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664870/reification-of-term-equality-inequality).

First, we first define `list_memberd_t/3`, which behaves just like the [`memberd_truth/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) but has a different argument order:

```
list_memberd_t([]    ,_,false).
list_memberd_t([Y|Ys],X,Truth) :-
   if_(X=Y, Truth=true, list_memberd_t(Ys,X,Truth)).

list_memberd_truth(Xs,X,Truth) :- list_memberd_t(Xs,X,Truth).
```

For the sake of brevity, let's define `memberd_t/3` based on `list_memberd_t/3`:

```
memberd_t(X,Xs,Truth) :- list_memberd_t(Xs,X,Truth).
```

As a parallel to `library(apply)`, let's define `tinclude/3`:

```
:- meta_predicate tinclude(2,?,?).
tinclude(P_2,Xs,Zs) :- 
    list_tinclude_list(Xs,P_2,Zs).

list_tinclude_list([],   _P_2,[]).
list_tinclude_list([E|Es],P_2,Fs0) :-
    if_(call(P_2,E), Fs0 = [E|Fs], Fs0 = Fs),
    list_tinclude_list(Es,P_2,Fs).
```

`tfilter/3` is another name for `tinclude/3`:

```
tfilter(P_2,As,Bs) :-
   tinclude(P_2,As,Bs).
```

Next, we define the meta-predicate `texclude/3`, the opposite of [`tinclude/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22053194/4609915):

```
:- meta_predicate texclude(2,?,?).
texclude(P_2,Xs,Zs) :- 
    list_texclude_list(Xs,P_2,Zs).

list_texclude_list([],_,[]).
list_texclude_list([E|Es],P_2,Fs0) :-
    if_(call(P_2,E), Fs0 = Fs, Fs0 = [E|Fs]),
    list_texclude_list(Es,P_2,Fs).
```

Now let's use them together!

```
?- texclude(list_memberd_truth([a,e,i,o,u]),
            [d,e,l,e,t,e,' ',v,o,w,e,l,s,' ',i,n,' ',a,' ',l,i,s,t], Filtered).
Filtered  = [d,  l,  t,  ' ',v,  w,  l,s,' ',  n,' ',  ' ',l,  s,t].
```

---

#### Edit

As an alternative to using above `texclude/3`, let's use `tinclude/3` with an auxiliary predicate `not/3` to flip the truth value:

```
:- meta_predicate not(2,?,?).
not(P_2,X,Truth) :-
   call(P_2,X,Truth0),
   truth_flipped(Truth0,Truth).

truth_flipped(true,false).
truth_flipped(false,true).
```

Sample query:

```
?- tinclude(not(list_memberd_truth([a,e,i,o,u])),
            [d,e,l,e,t,e,' ',v,o,w,e,l,s,' ',i,n,' ',a,' ',l,i,s,t], Filtered).
Filtered  = [d,  l,  t,  ' ',v,  w,  l,s,' ',  n,' ',  ' ',l,  s,t].
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use a clean form of negation instead?

Comment: @false. What is the alternative? Describing the set directly?

Comment: `tfilter(not(list_memberd_truth([a,e,i,o,u])), Xs, Ys).` with an appropriate definition of `not/2`.

Answer (score 1):

here a solution using DCG. Note how the 'output' is obtained (no arguments passing, only difference lists)

```
novowels --> ("a";"e";"i";"o";"u"), !, novowels.
% or ..
% novowels --> [C], {memberchk(C, "aeiou")}, !, novowels.
novowels, [C] --> [C], !, novowels.
novowels --> [].
```

I must confess the second cut doesn't like me, but seems required.

test:

```
?- phrase(novowels, "abcdefghilmnopq", L),format('~s',[L]).
bcdfghlmnpq
L = [98, 99, 100, 102, 103, 104, 108, 109, 110|...].
```

**edit** About the second cut, it seems required by 'left hand' notation: if I code with argument, without cut, I get a correct parsing:

```
novowels(Cs) --> ("a";"e";"i";"o";"u"), !, novowels(Cs).
% novowels(Cs) --> [C], {memberchk(C, "aeiou")}, !, novowels(Cs).
novowels([C|Cs]) --> [C], novowels(Cs).
novowels([]) --> [].
```

test:

```
?- phrase(novowels(L), "abcdefghilmnopq"),format('~s',[L]).
bcdfghlmnpq
L = [98, 99, 100, 102, 103, 104, 108, 109, 110|...] ;
false.
```

I wonder if this is a bug of the DCG translator, or (more probably) my fault...