# Count number of matching elements in two lists

Tags: prolog

I have 2 lists with random number of elemets. Eg A=[1,2,4,5] and B=[1,2,3]. Result should be 2.
Code that I tried:

```
domains
Numbers1 = integer*
Numbers2 = integer*
int_list=integer*

predicates
nondeterm prinadl(integer, int_list)

clauses
   //here going the code that read number that I've entered, and according to entered numer,programm should do something
 answer(T):- T=5, 
    P = 0,
    write ("Enter the 1st list"), readterm (int_list, L),
    write ("Enter the 2nd list"), readterm (int_list, L2),
    L2 = [H|V], prinadl(H, L), P1 = P + 1,
    write(L2, P1, V).

 prinadl (X, L):- L=[X|_], !.
 prinadl (X, L):- L=[_|T], prinadl (X, T).
```

I'm totally new with prolog. Can you please say me where I'm wrong? All I need is to get number of matches printed to the console.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems mostly random code... what's the logic your're following ? should be easy as visiting both lists and adding 1 to a result when both elements match

Comment: @CapelliC Yes, it almost random, I copied parts from different examples. Not sure how should I orginize 2 nested 'foreach's
I mean: how can I pick the first element from the first list and check all elements in L2, then pick up the second element of L and check thorugh L2

Comment: Handle visiting *both* lists with a single recursive predicate, you should add a counter that gets incremented when both lists have the same head. Don't forget that the visit will stop when one of the lists gets empty. There you can 'initialize' the counter to 0.

Comment: You don't say what the error is. There are a lot of empty spaces between predicate names and argument lists, for example `write (...`. Does the code even compile?

Comment: Why don't you start with test cases?

Comment: What's the result for A=[1,1] and B=[1]? For A=[1,2], B=[2,1]?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use Turbo Prolog or Visual Prolog. Are you required to use this? Can you use "more real" Prolog, like SWI, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on two things: first, guesswork. second, [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) by @false.

Let's define 
the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  `count_left_while2/4`.

`count_left_while2(P_2,Xs,Ys,N)`
counts
the number `N` of corresponding list items in `Xs` and `Ys` fulfilling `P_2`. Proceeding from left to right, `count_left_while2` stops at the first two items not satisfying `P_2`. It also stops  when one list is empty, but the other one is not.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

:- meta_predicate count_left_while2(2,?,?,?).
count_left_while2(P_2,Xs,Ys,N) :-
    N #>= 0,
    list_list_countleft_while(Xs,Ys,N,P_2).

nil_or_cons([]).
nil_or_cons([_|_]).

:- meta_predicate list_list_countleft_while(?,?,?,2).
list_list_countleft_while([],Xs,0,_) :-
    nil_or_cons(Xs).
list_list_countleft_while([X|Xs],Ys,N,P_2) :-
    list_list_prev_countleft_while(Ys,Xs,X,N,P_2).

:- meta_predicate list_list_prev_countleft_while(?,?,?,?,2).
list_list_prev_countleft_while([],_,_,0,_).
list_list_prev_countleft_while([Y|Ys],Xs,X,N,P_2) :-
    if_(call(P_2,X,Y),
        ( N0 #>= 0, N #= N0+1, list_list_countleft_while(Xs,Ys,N0,P_2) ),
        N = 0).
```

Let's use it in combination with reified term equality predicate [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915), like this:

```
:- count_left_while2(=,[1,2,4,5],[1,2,3],N).
N = 2.
```

Comment: @false. Fine with me! How do I find a proper name for the negation? `nonnil_and_noncons_t/2`?

Comment: @false. `other_than_nil_and_cons/2`. I wonder if the name invites reading as intended.

Comment: @false. Like atoms, quoted like this? `'not(nil_or_cons)'(X) :- ... .`

Comment: @false. I fail to see how to concat the name parts.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/772868) for a definition of `not/3`.