# Splitting list in prolog based on condition

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-dif

I have a list

```
[a,a,a,a,b,b]
```

My objective is to split it into

```
[[a,a,a,a],[b,b]]
```

the predicate i have implemented so far

```
split1([],[]).
split1([A1|T],[[H1,H2]|B]):-
A1=[H1,H2],
H1=H2,
split(T,B).

split1([],[]).
split1([A1|T],[[H1,H2]|B]):-
A1=[H1,H2],
H1\=H2,
split(T,B).
```

Sorry for the noob question learning prolog.

Comment: What happens when you try to evaluate your predicate? What did you expect will happen? Did you try to trace your program to see where it goes wrong (if it does)?

Comment: What answer to you expect for `[a,a,a,b,b,a,b,a,a]`?

Comment: [[a,a,a],[b,b],[a],[b],[a,a]]

Comment: Please try to format (indent) your programs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be approached very similarly to [your other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599450/assignment-that-implements-a-list-in-compact-form). Here are the related ideas.

You're going to need to keep a running *list* of repeated elements since your results have counters. So consider an auxiliary predicate that includes the current running list of repeats. This kind of "running list" is commonly used in Prolog and referred to as an *accumulator*.

```
split(L, C) :-
    split(L, [], C).   % Start repeat list accumulator at []
```

Now you'll need to consider a few different cases:

```
split([], _, []).                 % This is an easy one!
```

This says that if I compress an empty list, I get an empty list.

```
split([H], A, [[H|A]]).           % This is an easy one!
```

This one says if I gather a list of one element and my current running repeat list is `A`, then the result is `[[H|A]]`.

```
split([H, H|T], A, TC) :-
    ...
```

This is the case where I have a running repeat list, `A`, and the element is still repeating. The result is going to be a list `TC` but I don't know what it looks like yet since we're still in a repeating cycle and it will need to be determined through recursion. What should this predicate look like? The recursive call to `split1` which will be needed in this clause will have a new accumulator list. What does it look like?.

```
split([H1, H2|T], A, [[H1|A]|TC]) :-
    dif(H1, H2),
    ...
```

This is the case where I have a running repeat list, `A`, and the repeating stops at `H1`. Since the repeating of the current cycle ends with `H1`, we know the result looks like `[[H1|A]|TC]` because the repeat cycle has finished with `H1`, and the entire repeating list is `H1` with tail `A` (which just prepends `H1` to `A`, and they're all the same element). We just have yet to determine the rest of the list `TC` through recursion. What should this predicate implementation look like?

There are other ways of doing the above logic (e.g., with `->` and `;` construct, etc), but this will keep it simple.

Try to think of these as rules where the head of the predicate clause is the assertion which will be true if the following elements of the clause are true. And think recursively.

---

As an afterthought, this could be done without a separate accumulator by using the result to carry the accumulator:

```
split([], []).
split([H], [[H]]).
split([H1,H2|T], [[H1]|R]) :-
    dif(H1, H2),
    split(...).                 % left as an exercise
split([H,H|T], [[H|TH]|R]) :-
    split(...).                 % left as an exercise
```

Comment: s(X): "..., but this will keep it simple." Not just simple, but *correct*.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is [`splitlistIfAdj/3` and `dif/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915). Sample use:

```
?- splitlistIfAdj(dif, [a,a,a,b,b,c,a,a,a,a], Xss).
Xss = [[a,a,a],[b,b],[c],[a,a,a,a]].
```

Comment: If only one didn't have to additionally define `splitlistIfAdj/3`, `dif/3`, and `if_/3`.... And what's up with the camelCase btw?

Comment: Regarding the camelCase... a bad habit, I know.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about the additional definitions. We all use other library predicates, too, even if their implementation is often *quite brittle*.

Comment: I do see value in your answer (so +1 etc). However, this solution you present, while useful in another context, is a terrible overkill. You are _secretly_ solving a whole lot of potential problems that you don't discuss, and that OP has never encountered.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [SWI-Prolog implementation of `group_pairs_by_key/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/pairs.pl?show=src#group_pairs_by_key/2). It does a bit more than what you need, but I guess it is easy to leave out the unnecessary parts.

With the predicate as it is at the moment, you can do:

```
?- L = [a,a,b,b,a,b,b],
   keys_values_pairs(L, L, P),
   group_pairs_by_key(P, G),
   keys_values_pairs(_, Result, G).
L = [a, a, b, b, a, b, b],
P = [a-a, a-a, b-b, b-b, a-a, b-b, b-b],
G = [a-[a, a], b-[b, b], a-[a], b-[b, b]],
Result = [[a, a], [b, b], [a], [b, b]].
```

So you just need to figure out what to leave out to get a predicate that does not need a **pair** of a key and a value, but only a single value. Since this is obviously homework and since you didn't even put enough effort in the answer, I will leave this as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

an easy definition:

```
groups([X|Xs],[G|Gs]) :- take(X,Xs,G,Rs), groups(Rs, Gs).
groups([],[]).

take(X,[X|R],[X|G],S) :- !, take(X,R,G,S).
take(X,R,[X],R).
```

take/4 consumes and stores matching elements, leaving the remainder to group

Comment: @repeat: how could that happens ? unifying 123 with a list ?

Comment: My bad! I re-did the test and it worked. I made an error pasting your code into the Prolog interpreter... Sorry about the fuzz.

Comment: @repeat: thanks. Please, forgive naiveness of my answer, its meant for a beginner, that I think need to grasp the basic of Prolog before digging in advanced issues