# Deleting unwanted elements from list in PROLOG

Tags: prolog

I have a list, for example [(1,2), (3,4), (5,2), (4,2), (8,0)], and I want to remove, for example, all elements that are not (_,2). So in this case, I'd end up with a list like this: [(1,2), (5,2), (4,2)].
I was trying:

```
   conta_pos(NL, _, NL):-
      Idk what to do here, !.

   conta_pos([(L,C)|T], C, _):-
      conta_pos_aux([()], C, _).  

    conta_pos([(_,C)|T], _, _):-
      conta_pos(T, _, _).
```

The first argument represents the initial list, the second is the element I want the list to keep, and the third would be my new list.
Keep in mind that I'm very new to Prolog, please.

(The actual thing I want to do is to count the number of elements in the initial that are, in this example (_, 2), so that would 3. I was thinking of then using length\2 to count them, but if you have a better suggestion, I'm all open to it! And if you want to know what the whole thing I have to do is, feel free to ask)

Comment: "And if you want to know what the whole thing I have to do is, feel free to ask)" I ask !

Comment: @joel76 Okay, here it is: I must write a function, let's call it a/4. First argument is a list of 3 lists, I only need the 3rd, which is a list of ints I will call L. The second is a list that looks like the one in my question, and so is the 4th, I'll calm them Y and Z. The 3rd is just a int, I'll call N, which is the size of L.

Comment: @joel76 This is hard to explain, you'd probably need the entire assignment, but the whole thing is about a table, basically, each element of L is the maximum of elements each column of the table can have, from the 1st, to the Nth column. It can look like [1, 6, 3], so the 1st column can only have 1 element, the 2nd 6, and the 3rd 3.
Z and Y are lists that have elements representing elements of the table, with the row and column.
They can look like [(1,5), (3,2), (4,8)]. I used append and sort, to mix Y and Z and remove repeated elements.

Comment: @joel76 What I now have to do, is see if the number of elements that look like ('any row', 1) exceed the allowed number of elements in the 1st column. Then ('any row', 2) for the 2nd, etc...

Answer (score 3):

You're describing lists, so you could use DCGs for the task, since they usually yield easily readable code. Furthermore, you could use an additional argument to count the elements in the list as it's being traversed. Consider the following code:

```
list_filtered_length(L,F,Len) :-    % the filtered list F is described
   phrase(filtered_len(L,Len,0),F). % by the DCG filtered_len//3 

filtered_len([],N,N) -->            % if the list is empty, the counter is the length
   [].                              % and the filtered list is empty
filtered_len([(A,2)|Ps],N,C0) -->   % if the head of the list is (A,2)
   {C1 is C0+1},                    % the counter is increased
   [(A,2)],                         % (A,2) is in the filtered list
   filtered_len(Ps,N,C1).           % the same for the tail
filtered_len([(_,B)|Ps],N,C) -->    % if the head of the list is (_,B)
   {dif(B,2)},                      % with B not being 2, it's not in the list
   filtered_len(Ps,N,C).            % the same for the tail
```

Querying this predicate with your example yields the desired result:

```
?- list_filtered_length([(1,2),(3,4),(5,2),(4,2),(8,0)],F,Len).
F = [ (1, 2), (5, 2), (4, 2)],
Len = 3 ;
false.
```

Obviously, if you want to apply a different filter, you have to rewrite the two recursive DCG rules. It would be nicer to have the filter defined as a separate predicate and to pass it as an argument, therefore making the predicate more versatile. It would also be nice to have the predicate succeed deterministically if there's only a single solution. This can be realized with [if_/3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/6101159) and [(=)/3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/6101159). In order to be used as the first argument of `if_/3`, the filter predicate needs to reify its truth value as an additional argument:

```
filter_t((_,X),T) :-
   if_(X=2,T=true,T=false).
```

As you can see, the last argument is `true` if the filter condition holds and `false` otherwise:

```
?- filter_t((1,1),T).
T = false.

?- filter_t((1,2),T).
T = true.
```

Now the predicate can be redefined with an additional argument for the filter like so:

```
list_filtered_by_length(L,LF,F_2,Len) :-    % F_2 is the filter argument
   phrase(filtered_by_len(L,F_2,Len,0),LF).

filtered_by_len([],_F_2,N,N) -->
   [].
filtered_by_len([P|Ps],F_2,N,C0) -->
   {if_(call(F_2,P),(X=[P], C1 is C0+1),
                    (X=[], C1 = C0))},
   X,                                       % X is in the filtered list
   filtered_by_len(Ps,F_2,N,C1).
```

If the head of the list meets the filter condition (`call(F_2,P)`), it is in the filtered list (`X=[P]`) and the counter is increased (`C1 is C0+1`), otherwise it is not in the list (`X=[]`) and the counter is not increased (`C1 = C0`).

Now the example query succeeds deterministically:

```
?- list_filtered_by_length([(1,2),(3,4),(5,2),(4,2),(8,0)],F,filter_t,Len).
F = [ (1, 2), (5, 2), (4, 2)],
Len = 3.
```

If you want to filter for something else, just define a different filter predicate. For example, if you want to filter all pairs of equal elements from a list of pairs, you can define...

```
filter2_t(X-Y,T) :-
   if_(X=Y,T=true,T=false).
```

... and then query:

```
?- list_filtered_by_length([a-a,b-c,d-d,e-f],F,filter2_t,Len).
F = [a-a, d-d],
Len = 2.
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you can express this relation quite compactly by using [tfilter/3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/6101159), as suggested by @false in the comments. Just as with the DCG version you pass a reifying filter predicate as third argument that is then used as the first argument of `tfilter/3`. Subsequently the length of the filtered list is described by the built-in `length/2`.

```
list_filtered_by_length(L,FL,F_2,Len) :-
   tfilter(F_2,L,FL),
   length(FL,Len).
```

The above queries yield the same answers as with the DCG version.

Comment: Why no `tfilter/3`?

Comment: What is so bad in using `length/2` here?

Comment: @false: Good point, I added a version using `tfilter/3`. Regarding using `length/2`: There's nothing wrong with that. I just figured, since the list is traversed by the DCG anyway, counting the length could be done at the same time with additional arguments thus traversing the list only once.

Comment: Variables holding continuations are better marked with e.g. `_2` to show that they still lack two arguments.

Comment: @false: Yes, it's definitely better this way, thanks for the hint :-)

Answer (score 1):

In general, suppose that you have a predicate `some_condition(...other_args..., X)` that succeeds if you want to keep `X` and fails otherwise. A simple recursion to do the filter would be:

```
filter([], _, []).
filter([X|Xs], Condition, Ys) :-
    (    call(Condition, X)
    ->   Ys = [X|Zs]
    ;    Ys = Zs
    ),
    filter(Xs, Condition, Zs).
```

You can then call this as:

```
filter(RawList, some_condition(...other args...), FilteredList).
```

In this specific case, the condition you want to check is whether the argument matches `(_,2)`. The simplistic condition would be:

```
second_arg_2((_,2)).  % Succeeds if second argument is a 2
```

You can make the condition as sophisticated as you wish to handle more cases.

Then you can call:

```
| ?- filter([(1,2), (3,4), (5,2), (4,2), (8,0)], second_arg_2, R).

R = [(1,2),(5,2),(4,2)]

yes
```

You can then, of course, count the results if you want using `length/2`.

Answer (score 0):

For the count of (_,2) you can do

```
conta_pos(In, (_,V), Out) :-
    aggregate(count, X^member((X,V), In), Out).
```

Result :

```
?- conta_pos( [(1,2), (3,4), (5,2), (4,2), (8,0)], (_,2), Out).
Out = 3.
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtering elements matching (via unification) with a template, we have two recursive rules (one for when the element matches Z, and one for when the element does not match):

```
filter([X|Xs],Z,[X|Ys]) :- % X is part of the output
    copy_term(Z,E),        % copy free variables (e.g. the _ in (_,2))
    E=X,                   % matches with template Z
    filter(Xs,Z,Ys).       % recurse

filter([X|Xs],Z,Ys) :-     % X is not part of the output
    copy_term(Z,E),        % copy free variables
    E\=X,                  % does NOT match with template Z
    filter(Xs,Z,Ys).       % recurse

filter([],_,[]).           % base step
```

We have to use `copy_term/2` to generate a new copy of free variables, otherwise it will ground the matching variables at the first step and try to match the grounded template against the remaining elements, and would fail.

```
?- filter([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 2), (4, 2), (8, 0)], (_, 2), Y), length(Y, Count).
Y = [(1, 2),  (5, 2),  (4, 2)],
Count = 3
```

Alternatively, you can directly count the matching elements with a recursive predicate, which works exactly the same as the previous solution:

```
count([X|Xs],Z,Count) :-
    copy_term(Z,E),
    E=X,
    count(Xs,Z,Count1),
    Count is Count1 + 1.

count([X|Xs],Z,Count) :-
    copy_term(Z,E),
    E\=X,
    count(Xs,Z,Count).

count([],_,0).
```

Test:

```
?- count([(1,2), (3,4), (5,2), (4,2), (8,0)], (_,2), Count).
Count = 3
```

The two recursive rules can be merged into one, with the conditional (`->`) operator:

```
count([X|Xs],Z,Count) :-
    copy_term(Z,E),
    count(Xs,Z,Count1),
    ( E=X -> Count is Count1 + 1 ; Count=Count1 ).

count([],_,0).
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!
I still have some things on my assignment left to do, if you're interested ^^'